# Convert a Cygwin PID to a Windows PID

Tags: shell, cygwin, sysinternals

I have a process I spawn with a [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) shell script, and I am unable to kill it with the `kill` command. Even with the [Cygwin kill](http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-utils.html#kill) with the `-f` option, I get this message:

```
kill: couldn't open pid 1234
```

I would like to try to kill it with [PsKill](http://technet.microsoft.com/sysinternals/bb896683.aspx), but I cannot find a way to convert the `Cygwin PID` to a `Windows PID` that `PsKill` will understand. How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried running the cygwin kill instead of the bash builtin? If it is a Windows PID then type:

```
/bin/kill -f 1234
```

or if it is a Cygwin PID then type:

```
/bin/kill -9 1234
```

As far as I know there is no API to Cygwin that you could call to translate a Cygwin PID to a Windows PID. However, you could parse the output of `ps -W` to do the conversion. Or, if you really, really don't want to do that, then have a look at the source code for the Cygwin `ps` command, and see where they get the pids from. The Cygwin [ps source code is here.](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/src/winsup/utils/ps.cc?rev=1.26&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup&cvsroot=src). You could write a small utility in C to take the Cygwin pid and give you a Windows pid.

Comment: Yes, it is the Cygwin kill I'm using. I tried /bin/kill -f -9 1234 and /bin/kill -9 1234 with no success. 1234 is a Cygwin PID.

Comment: If you use -f, then you should give it the Windows PID from ps -W

Comment: Apart from this great answer - sometimes when the process is locked from inside Windows, Cygwin kill spawns the "couldn't open pid 1234" message. The process then needs to be unlocked from inside Windows first.

Comment: Thank you for this distinction! I was going crazy trying to figure out why "kill -f <pid>" wasn't working for a windows pid. That's going into the "never forget this!" file for Cygwin commands. :)

Answer (score 9):

`ps -W` will show the Windows PID in addition to the Cygwin PID.

Or, you can do it programmatically like this:

```
#include <sys/cygwin.h>
winpid = cygwin_internal(CW_CYGWIN_PID_TO_WINPID, cygpid);
```

Answer (score 8):

The [proc file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs) has the windows PID for cygwin PID $pid in `/proc/$pid/winpid`.

```
> notepad&
[1] 11716
> taskkill /f /pid $(</proc/$!/winpid)
ERFOLGREICH: Der Prozess mit PID 11976 wurde beendet.
[1]+  Exit 1                  notepad
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to kill running Bash scripts from Cygwin is using the [Sysinternals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pskill) tool `PsKill64.exe`. The reason is that Cygwin's `ps` also give PID's that are different from `WINPID`.

In addition, `pskill` also has the `-t` flag that kills the entire process tree, which means any other threads/sub-processes that your script may have started. Of course `kill -9 <PID>` also works, but it doesn't kill descendants already started by the script.

```sh
# cat sleeper.sh
ZID=$$
WINPID=$(cat /proc/${ZID}/winpid)
echo "WINPID: ${WINPID}"
sleep 10
```

Now run with:

```
$ ./sleeper.sh &
[1] 8132
WINPID: 8132

$ ps
      PID    PPID    PGID     WINPID   TTY         UID    STIME COMMAND
     #5280       1    5280       5280  ?           1001 14:21:40 /usr/bin/mintty
     #7496    5684    7496       3836  pty0        1001 20:48:12 /usr/bin/ps
     #5684    5280    5684       6052  pty0        1001 14:21:40 /usr/bin/bash
     5948    8132    8132       3900  pty0        1001 20:48:11 /usr/bin/sleep
     8132    5684    8132       8132  pty0        1001 20:48:11 /usr/bin/bash
```

As you see, this starts two processes, the main `bash` script and the sleep thread. So if you `kill -1 8132` the sleep thread will continue running, but if you use `pskill64 -t 8132`, you will kill all its descendants too. Analogous to the linux `killall` command.

Answer (score 1):

This works in sh shell:

```
./${Z_BIN} &
Z_PID=$!
Z_PIDW=`ps -p ${Z_PID} | awk -e '/^[[:space:]]+[[:digit:]+]/{print $4}'`
```

Z_BIN contains your program to execute. Z_PID will contain cygwin pid and Z_PIDW will contain windows pid for the same program. You can save Z_PIDW in to a pid file and use it later for killing or any other purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I searched the web to see if anyone had a function or script to convert cygwin PIDs to Microsoft PIDs. I found none; so I made my own. I am putting it up here for safe keeping (when I do not have access to my life-time of scripts that I have programmed). This is becoming a frequent solution for me out in the wild.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env bash
    # Convert a cygwin PID to a Microsoft PID using bash and perl
    ps -W | perl -e '
    my ($line, $arg,$errno,@columns);
    $errno=1;
    while($line = ){
      chomp($line);
      $line=~s/^\s+//g;s/\s+$//g;
      for $arg (@ARGV){
        if ($line=~/^${arg}/){
          $errno=0;
          @columns=split(/\s+/,$line);
          print STDOUT $columns[3];
          last;
        }
      }
    }
    exit($errno);
    ' "${@}"
```

```
The kill using `taskkill` and/or `kill` cygwin terminal.
<pre><code>
taskkill /F /IM ${m1crosoft_pid_goes_here}
kill -9 ${cygwin_pid_goes_here_tmp}
```

Use file descriptor when you can and use instead of that pipe.

Comment: The grammar and copy+paste text got mis-interpreted at the bottom there. But my stackexhange.com jujitsu is not great. I'm out.